# Cannot serialize/deserialize bidirectional references using Jackson JSON in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I have intentionally created complex Java classes hierarchy, which also can occur on production in order to test Jackson JSON serialization and deserialization. Some annotations, like `@Getter` are Lombok ones.

DemoI.java

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "interface",
        defaultImpl = DemoImpl.class
)
@JsonSubTypes(
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DemoImpl.class, name = "demoImpl")
)
public interface DemoI {
}
```

DemoImpl.java

```
public class DemoImpl implements DemoI {
    @Getter
    private int age;
    @Getter
    private String name;
    @Getter
    private DemoAbst demoAbst;

    @JsonCreator
    public DemoImpl(@JsonProperty("age") int age,
                    @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                    @JsonProperty("demoAbst") DemoAbst demoAbst) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.demoAbst = demoAbst;
    }
}
```

DemoAbst.java

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "abstract",
        defaultImpl = DemoAbstImpl.class
)
@JsonSubTypes(
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DemoAbstImpl.class, name = "demoAbstImpl")
)
public abstract class DemoAbst {
}
```

DemoAbstImpl.java

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id"
)
public class DemoAbstImpl extends DemoAbst{
    @Getter
    private final int id = 1;
    @Getter
    private int song;
    @Getter
    private final DemoAbstImplImpl demoAbstImplImpl;

    public DemoAbstImpl(int song) {
        this.song = song;
        this.demoAbstImplImpl = new DemoAbstImplImpl("song", this);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public DemoAbstImpl(@JsonProperty("song") int song,
                        @JsonProperty("demoAbstImplImpl") DemoAbstImplImpl d) {
        this.song = song;
        this.demoAbstImplImpl = d;
    }

}
```

DemoAbstImplImpl.java

```
public class DemoAbstImplImpl {
    @Getter
    private String koo;
    @Getter
    private final DemoAbstImpl demoAbstImpl;

    @JsonCreator
    public DemoAbstImplImpl(@JsonProperty("koo") String koo,
                            @JsonProperty("demoAbstImpl") DemoAbstImpl d) {
        this.koo = koo;
        this.demoAbstImpl = d;
    }
}
```

And finally, the Main.java

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DemoAbstImpl dai = new DemoAbstImpl(67);

        DemoI di = new DemoImpl(1, "Hello", dai);


        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        byte[] b = om.writeValueAsBytes(di);
        Files.write(Path.of("out.json"), b);

        DemoI di2 = om.readValue(new File("out.json"), DemoI.class);
```

When I serialize, I got following JSON

```
{
  "interface": "demoImpl",
  "age": 1,
  "name": "Hello",
  "demoAbst": {
    "abstract": "demoAbstImpl",
    "id": 1,
    "song": 67,
    "demoAbstImplImpl": {
      "koo": "song",
      "demoAbstImpl": 1,
      "id": 2
    }
  }
}
```

For me, that `demoAbstImpl: 1` doesn't make sense at all, seems that Jackson uses it as a reference, but why Jackson doesn't follow that reference till the end, i.e `until it reaches the value`.

And also deserialization ends up with an error `Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Could not resolve Object Id [1] (for [simple type, com.example.mytest.DemoAbstImpl]).`

Any ideas, how to fix that? At least for me, the code seems very correct, and no issues should be with Jackson annotations.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the output you want or expect? Also, what do you expect it to do when deserializing? To me, it looks like it's doing exactly what the annotations say to do. The cyclical relationship is a problem when deserializing using arguments to a `@JsonCreator` constructor instead of setters: one of the objects has to be created first.